# How to originate a smart contract with Taquito

Tags: operation, javascript

How can I access my contract after originating it using taquito? If I use taquito like this.

`Tezos.contract.originate({...contractOptions})`

How can I access my new originated address and start using my new contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inject any kind of operation using taquito you will get an Operation object back which can allow you to interact with the result of your operation.

In the case of Origination you will be able to interact with your newly deployed contract doing:

```
const op = Tezos.contract.originate({...contractOptions})
const contract = await op.contract()
```

This will wait for your contract to be originated and will give you the taquito smart contract abstraction object.